# Customers: create products

Tags: customer, magento-1.9

I need to add the possibility a customer can create products like for admin or other system users.

Is it possibile or is there a plugin ?

Thanks

Comment: That is a marketplace, Magento is not friendly to those environments. There are some extensions is you search, however they are not ideal. We generally link an external tool which is the data entry portal and auto data load in to Magento, better for admin/customer separation and security.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide permission for a customer from backend and provide role for catalog.

Then customer can upload his product in manage product section. Also he can remove any product.

> System >Permissions > Manage Users/Roles

This might help you. Click on the following [LINK](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ce18-and-ee113-admin-users-roles)